# Undefined index Jquery Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this small but annoying problem. I really not usual with a web thing. I try to request to my php file using ajax jquery. When I want to retrieve the data I send from ajax, it return undefined index. I dunno what's the problem, it make me spend a lot of time to solve it. Thanks

Below is my ajax code

```
var at=this.name.substring(this.name.length,7);
var value_header = $("#key"+at).val();
var jsObj = { new_value:value_header, id:at, data:'header'};
console.log(JSON.stringify(jsObj));
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  headers: 'application/urlformencoded',
  url: 'admin_crud.php',
  data: jsObj,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data){
  console.log("Sukses");
}
```

When I call the below code in my php file, the result is 'Undefined index: data'

```
echo $_POST['data'];
```

//Edit
So, when I try var_dump($_POST);, the result is array(0) {}. Where is my mistake? I thought I had send the right one
//Edit

As I mention above, I want it to run perfect without error. Thanks

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: So you see `undefined index` when you open `admin_crud.php` directly, or in `console.log` when you run the ajax?

Comment: @imvain2 directly to admin_crud.php

Comment: @aynber I edit my question, you can see there

Comment: @BOBBYIRAWAN, that will always happen. Your php is expecting those variables to be passed via POST. However, when you open the file without submitting data, your programming isn't receiving the data it needs.

Comment: @imvain2 so my mistake is the way i send the data? that's what you mean?

Comment: If you want the data SAVED for future use, you will need to save it to a database, file or even a cookie/session etc..

Comment: @imvain2 i don't need a complicate thing like that, just need to send a simple data, just that

Comment: You should var_dump as anyber suggests, undifined index usually means it does not exist, might be your data returns as an object object

Comment: @BOBBYIRAWAN, sending itsn't your problem. Your problem is you want to access that data later on. If you want to access it later on you need a method to store it. Simply submitting the data via post doesn't allow you to access that data again when you don't resubmit it via post.

Comment: @JellyBean I've done it, the result is empty array, but I did send the data, you can see it in my code

Comment: When your ajax code is sending the data, it makes a request to the url, using the http method POST and passes the post-data in the request body. The PHP file can then use those values. If you access the PHP-page directly, it's a completely new request, using GET and no data which has nothing to do with your ajax request. The page doesn't "remember" what other requests posted. In your `success`-function, use: `console.log(data);` to log what the PHP-code actually returns.

Comment: Thanks for you guys comment and time, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `headers`, change your `datatype` to `text` and `catch errors` in the `ajax call`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    data: jsObj,
    url: "admin_crud.php",

    success: function (result) {
        console.log("success", result);
    },

    error: function (e) {
        console.log("Unsuccessful:", e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution beside @Marco Sanchez too, I don't know it always work or not, but in my case, it work :

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'admin_crud.php',
  headers: "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  data: "new_value="+value_header+"&id="+at+"&data=header",
  success: function(data){
     console.log("Sukses");
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```